# Show an Android style toast notification using HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Normally when you would like to make a user aware of something you use an alert.

Now say I would like to do that but in a *Android toast* like way, namely a popup that shows up on screen but then a few seconds later *disappears by itself* so the user won't have to bother closing it, like the image below.

How could something like this be achieved in the web?
Note: Doing a touch interface so that's the reason I would like to have it in this way

[image]

Comment: A jQuery toastmessage plugin will do.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The easier way is to make a holder where you put your message. That holder will be hidden.

```
<div class='error' style='display:none'>Event Created</div>
```

You add some CSS magic

```
.error {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    bottom:10px;
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
}
```

Then with a simple script you can show it for a few seconds. Use `.stop()` if necessary

```
$('.error').fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400); //fade out after 3 seconds
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.error').text($(this).data('text')).fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400); 
});
```

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.error {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    bottom:10px;
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='error' style='display:none'></div>
<button data-text='I did something!'>Do something!</button>
```

[**jsFiddle version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/egxtU/184/)

This is a very basic example that can then be changed into a function with parameters which will give the text, color, duration and anything else you may need.

Below a more advanced (unnecessarily complicated) way (kinda like a plugin). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/x7cj66a4/6/) is also a fiddle version.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.aToast = function(options) {

    var $this = $(this),
      settings = $.extend({
        fadeOut: 400,
        fadeIn: 400,
        delay: 3000,
        text: 'Whoops! Something happened and I showed up.',
        toastListenEvent: 'click',
        aClass: false
      }, options),
      $at = false,
      aTevents = false;

    settings.toastListenEvent = settings.toastListenEvent + ' a-Toast';
    settings.aClass = 'aToast-view-message' 
                  + (settings.aClass ? ' ' + settings.aClass : '')
    if ($('[data-aToast=true]:not(.aToast-init)').length) 
      $this = $this.add($('[data-aToast=true]:not(.aToast-init)')
                                       .addClass('aToast-init'));

    function _remove() {
      $(this).stop().remove();
    }

    function _displayDiv() {
      $('.aToast-view-message').hide();
      var da = $(this).data('atoast-text');
      var $div = $('<div/>', {
          text: da ? da : settings.text,
          class: settings.aClass
        }).stop().fadeIn(settings.fadeIn)
        .delay(settings.delay)
        .fadeOut(settings.fadeOut, _remove)
        .appendTo('body');
    }

    $this.not('[data-aToast=false]').on(settings.toastListenEvent, _displayDiv);

  };
}(jQuery));

$('button').aToast({
  aClass: 'users-dont-care-about-this-class-name'
});

$('div').aToast({
  aClass: 'hehe',
  toastListenEvent: 'mouseenter',
  text: 'Okay, this is not working'
});


/* or 

$().aToast({
    aClass: 'users-dont-care-about-this-class-name'
});

To listen to data-aToast only

*/
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.aToast-view-message {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #383838;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Here goes nothing</button>
<input type='button' data-aToast='true' data-aToast-text='Hey there.' value='Woop!' />
<div style='display:inline-block'>I am a div! Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Here is forked version of Spokey's code that will create the div inline, thus no changes to your dom required: http://jsfiddle.net/abdullahadam/egxtU/266/

Comment: hi @Spokey.. I tried this in chrome and it's giving error "Uncaught TypeError: myDiv.stop is not a function"

Comment: without "stop()" it keeps doing same for multiple clicks

Comment: Hey @SurajS, think you could show an example in fiddle? .stop() will only stop the animation and run it from the start again when triggered. I think you might be looking for a way to disable the action?

Comment: I am Sorry.. it was issue with sytax.. I came to know when it started giving same error for all funtions.. thanx for your reply :)

Comment: Hi, @Spokey I want my toast to be above everything else. Right now it is getting hidden under one of my modal that I am using. I tried using z-index but it didn't work. Can you suggest me anything that might help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @Spokey I found out the solution on my own. Just had to change the position to fixed. I don't know how I missed it in the first place.
Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Yep, always place position for z-index to work! Glad it works though.

Answer (score 15):

You have some good libraries on internet to mimic the native android toast message:

- [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)
- https://github.com/jadjoubran/Android-Toast (Javascript)
- https://github.com/akquinet/jquery-toastmessage-plugin (jQuery)
- https://gist.github.com/kamranzafar/3136584 (jQuery Mobile)

Basically is a `div` with the message with some CSS and an animation to show and hide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will look into it, but preferably make one of my own as you state it wasn't as hard as I thought. :)

Comment: https://github.com/jadjoubran/Android-Toast is simple to get started with - only 2 files to copy-over/include from GitHub, and then 1-line to show the toast.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple CSS and Javascript solution. (Uses Jquery, but doesn't need to).

```js
$("#clickme").click(function() {
      $("body").append("<span class ='toast'>Hello World!</span>");

      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".toast").remove();
      },3000);
});
```

```css
.toast {
  position: fixed;
  display:block;

  bottom: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  left: calc(50% - 5em);

  animation: toast-fade-in 1s 2 alternate;


  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2em;

  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;

  opacity: 0;

}


@keyframes toast-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "clickme" type = "button" value = "click me!"/>
```

Comment: Thats, Totally. Awesome.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you want notification like this. Then code and instruction is here (Excuse me koding.com :)))

HTML side (add end of body)

```
<div id="notification" class="kdnotification main">
  <div class="kdnotification-title"></div>
</div>
```

CSS side

```
.kdnotification{display:none}
.kdnotification a{text-shadow:0 1px 0 #444}
.kdnotification{position:fixed;padding:10px;z-index:20001;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}
.kdnotification .kdnotification-title{color:#fff;font-size:24px;line-height:36px;margin:2px;font-weight:700}
.kdnotification .kdnotification-content{font-size:16px;line-height:18px;color:#fff}
.kdnotification .kdnotification-timer{position:absolute;top:21px;right:25px;color:#fff;line-height:15px;text-align:center;font-size:15px;width:20px;height:24px}
.kdnotification a{position:absolute;cursor:pointer;display:block;top:24px;right:5px;line-height:24px;text-align:center;font-size:24px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;width:20px;height:24px}
.kdnotification-title{font-size:18px;line-height:28px;float:none}
.kdnotification-title{font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-weight:400;float:none}
.kdnotification.mini{-webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;-moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;padding:1px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1),inset 0 0 2px #000;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1),inset 0 0 2px #000;box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1),inset 0 0 2px #000}
.kdnotification-title{font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-weight:400;float:none;padding:2px 10px}
.kdnotification.mini .kdnotification-title p{padding:0 10px}
.kdnotification.mini.error{background:rgba(185,74,72,.9);font-weight:600}
.kdnotification.mini.success{background:rgba(70,136,71,.8);font-weight:600}
```

JS side (of course using jquery library)

```
function notify(message,status){
  $('.kdnotification-title').html(message);
  funcking();
  if(status == 1){
    $('#notification').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,.4)'}).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
  } else {
    $('#notification').css({'background-color':'rgba(216,0,12,.6)'}).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
  }
}

function funcking(){
    var kd=$('.kdnotification');
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        kdheight = kd.height(),kdwidth = kd.width(),
        hdiff = viewportHeight - kdheight,
        vdiff = viewportWidth - kdwidth,
        left= vdiff/2,
        top = hdiff/2;
    kd.css({'top':top+'px','left':left+'px'});
}
```

Use case

```
if(success){
  notify("Success message",1);
} else {
  notify("Error message",0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Notify-js](https://github.com/morfat/notify-js)  library that  borrows a lot from [Toastr](https://github.com/morfat/notify-js) and simplifies it to something similar to android-toast.

It shows a `div` with some messages in it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this light and simple [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library which exactly matches with the android toast look & feel & it is only **1KB** in size.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```

### Visit [this page](https://toastmaker.wirehall.com/) to check more examples with beautiful styled toast messages