# Toast message in Oracle MAF

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf, oracle-adf-mobile

Is there any way to generate `toast` message in Oracle-MAF like in android or IOS ? I gone through some blogs but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create this pretty easily with some Javascript and CSS, see [Show an Android style toast notification using HTML/CSS/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723164/show-an-android-style-toast-notification-using-html-css-javascript)

Or you can also use a Cordova plugin, see: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Ok... is it applicable for ios?

Comment: Thank you User404.. I got it... :)