# Intel XDK Cordova Alert Design

Tags: cordova, intel

Intel XDK how can I change the alert box design?

https://scontent-amt2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t34.0-12/12596219_473268069531187_1594005360_n.jpg?oh=c9f9faf83cc8ca2246dc12f78a24323b&oe=56F2E2B3

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Mobile application ,its better to display a toast than alert box.
Please use the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723164/show-an-android-style-toast-notification-using-html-css-javascript) ,show how to display toast.